# how to call a code behind button_click in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I opened a Popup using Jquery dialog it contains all asp.net controls [ submit,textbox]

When i click submit on popup no action is performing.....how can i call that action with jQuery

i am beginner..can u explain in detail...if possible with sample code.......

Comment: Minor comment - I would rephrase "Popup" to "Modal Dialog", if you really are using jQuery dialog. "Popup" generally means something else -- a popup window.

Answer (score 0):

This is because jquery puts the dialog outside the form, and asp.net won't process it if it is outside the form.

When defining your dialog, use parent().appendTo("form") instead, and it will work:

```
$('#yourPanel').dialog({
  //options
}).parent().appendTo("form");
```